# VBA Expected:end of statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a formula below and I keep on getting the expected end of statement error

```
 Worksheets("Report").Cells(8,3).Value="='DATA'!B"&lRow-2&"*'DATA'!D"&lRow-2
```

The error occurs on `"*'DATA'!D"`

> Expected: End of statement

Answer (score 3):

When typing this line …

```
Worksheets("Report").Cells(8,3).Value="='DATA'!B"&lRow-2&"*'DATA'!D"&lRow-2
```

… into the editor make sure you have spaces in the correct places:

```
Worksheets("Report").Cells(8, 3).Value = "='DATA'!B" & lRow - 2 & "*'DATA'!D" & lRow - 2
```

Spacing is necessary because the `&` has 3 different meanings:

1. Without space: Declare a number to be of type `Long`:
   `2&` means that `2` is of type `Long`.
   (also see [Declaring variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables)).
2. With spaces: Concatenate two strings:
   `&` with spaces means concatenate strings eg. `TotalString = String1 & String2`
   (also see [&-Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator))
3. `&H` specifying a hexadecimal number:
   Example `&HF` means hexadecimal `F` and `Debug.Print &HF` will output 15 which is the hexadecimal `F` converted into a decimal number.

Comment: Thanks... I always wondered why it insists on spacing... clear now..

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheets("Report").Cells(8, 3).Value = "='DATA'!B" & lRow - 2 & "*'DATA'!D" & lRow - 2`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Yes, I already got this feedback in another post. I will add some extra explanation next times.

Comment: Or, even better, you could add some explanation this time by clicking 'edit' on your answer.